# How to know if email is sent from Content Builder. API call

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, content-builder

I have many business units and I'd like to know via API if the BU is sending emails using Content builder or classic content. I know classic content uses SOAP API and Content builder REST API, but I don't seem to find a way to know via API how the emails are being created or sent. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

One option to do this would be to use the Job data view and check for the last month's sends. In there there is a field called email name. You can lookup this manually in Content Builder and see if the email is sent from there. I'm sure there is a way of doing it via API but I didn't find much time to investigate. I hope this helps someone down the road.